# Iron Router template not registered on redirect

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have this simple check if user is logged in and if not - redirect to register page

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    onBeforeAction: function (pause) {
      if (!Meteor.user()) {
        this.render('register');
        pause();
      }
    }
  });

  this.route('register', {path: '/register'});
});
```

And getting

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function: Error: Couldn't find a template named "register" or "register". Are you sure you defined it?
```

When I go directly to `/register`, it does work.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

`this.render`  takes *template name* as argument, **not** *route name*

> this.render('templateName'): Render the template named 'templateName'
>   into the main yield {{> yield}}.

[Source](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md)

Replace `this.render("register")` with `Router.go('register')`

It is also beneficial to check if user is in logging in state:

```
    if (!(Meteor.loggingIn() || Meteor.user())) {
        console.log("User is not logged in");
        Router.go("register");
        pause()
    }
```

Comment: Using `render` instead of `go` *was* my intention, I see no reason to reload the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

To create the templates I was using the `em` tool and when I did `em g:route register` it named the template `Register` - with a capital `R`.

Renaming it in the render: `this.render('Register');` did the trick.